# Algorithmic order of growth of the code

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

I am attending a course online and stuck at the following question. What is the order of growth of the worst case running time of the following code fragment as a function of N?

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= N*N; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
            sum++;
```

I thought that it is of the order of `N^4` but it seems this answer is wrong. can you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One run of the inner loop increments `sum` exactly `j` times.

One run of the middle loop invokes the inner loop exactly `i` times, with values of `j` between `1` and `i` (inclusive). So it increments `sum` exactly `1+2+3+...i` times, which is `i.(i+1)/2` by the well-known "triangular numbers" formula.

The outer loop invokes the middle loop exactly `N^2` times (let us denote it as `M`), with values of `i` between `1` and `M` (inclusive). So it increments `sum` exactly `1+3+6+...M.(M+1)/2` times. Similarly, this is `M.(M+1).(M+2)/6`, by the not-so-well-known "tetrahedral numbers" formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral_number).

All in all, the final value of `sum` is `N^2.(N^2+1).(N^2+2)/6`.

Thinking in asymptotic terms, the inner loop is `O(j)`, the middle one `O(i^2)` (by summation) and the outer one `O(M^3)` (by summation), i.e. `O(N^6)`.

Also see Faulhaber's formula, which shows that the sum of `n^k` is `O(N^(k+1))` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Answer (score 6):

It is of order `O(N^6)`. You should note that it is not true that every loop simply add an order `N` to the complexity. Considering the following example:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= M; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++)
        for (int k = 1; k <= j; k++)
            sum++;
```

You should be able to figure out it is of order `O(M^3)` easily, so if you replace `M=N^2`, then you will get the answer. The key point is that every inner loop are of order `O(N^2)` in this case, but not `O(N)`.

Answer (score 3):

Let's denote `n = N^2`. Then, the loop will execute each time that `k <= i <= j`. This will be approximately `n^3/6` times. Thus, the runtime is `O(n^3)= O(N^6)`

---

*Explanation*: Ignoring for a moment the cases where `k==i` or `j==i` or `j==k`, 
we take 1 out of 6 distinct triples :

```
 (a1,a2,a3)
 (a1,a3,a2)
 (a2,a1,a3)
 (a2,a3,a1)
 (a3,a2,a1)
 (a3,a1,a2)
```

Overall, there are `n^3` triples. Only one out of 6 triples obeys the order.

Answer (score 1):

Any given run of the innermost (k) loop has a time proportional to j, but we've got to do one of those for each of j = 1 through j = i, and that sum 1 + 2 + … + i grows like i^2.  So for any *given* i we've got an O(i^2) running time, but of course we've got to deal with i = 1 through i = N^2.  The sum of i^2 for i = 1 through N^2 [happens to grow like N^6](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20x%2ax%20for%20x%20=%201%20to%20x=n%2an).